# Apply custom CSS on bs timepicker

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am using  ngx-bootstrap/timpicker component but would like to change its appearance so it can be used on  an iPad for my app by increasing the size of input and font size.

I have been able to increase the width and height of the input boxes and chevrons using the following css:

```
.bs-timepicker-field {
  width: 85px ;
  height: 75px;
  padding: .375rem .55rem;
  font-size: x-large ;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.bs-chevron {
  border-style: solid;
  display: block;
  width: 15px !important;
  height: 15px !important;
  position: relative;
  border-width: 3px 0px 0 3px;
}
```

but unable to change the size of AM/PM button.

Could someone please let me know how to change the font size of AM/PM text to larger size and a border around the button.

[image]

Comment: Please show the rendered markup and Bootstrap's CSS (or a live demo).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [the demo](https://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/timepicker), this increased both the font and button size:

```
timepicker .btn {
    font-size: 24px;
}
```